# Python Emailed PDF Arriving with no name

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, pdf

I found and extended a script that will scan a directory and then email the pdfs inside it. The problem occurs when I receive the email. The PDFs are arriving as 'noname' files without an extension. I have to download them and manually add the extension to display them. Is there something I am missing here??

```
import sys
import os
import smtplib
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

COMMASPACE = ', '

def main():
    sender = 'jp@voice.com'
    password = 'pword'
    recipients = 'j@gmail.com'

    # Create enclosing (outer) message
    outer = MIMEMultipart()
    outer['Subject'] = 'TEST EMAIL'
    outer['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(recipients)
    outer['From'] = sender
    outer.preamble = 'You will not see this in a MIMIE aware reader'

    # list of attachments
    attachments = r'C:/Users/Ace/Desktop/PDFTST/'
    attach = os.listdir(attachments)
    for file in attach:
        try:
            with open(attachments + file, 'rb') as fp:
                msg = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
                msg.set_payload(fp.read())
            encoders.encode_base64(msg)
            outer.attach(msg)
        except:
            print("unable to open the attach. Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
            raise

        composed = outer.as_string()

    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as s:
            s.ehlo()
            s.starttls()
            s.ehlo()
            s.login(sender, password)
            s.sendmail(sender, recipients, composed)
            s.close()
        print("email sent!!!!")
    except:
        print("Unable to send email. Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set the MIME type to application/pdf, not application/octet-stream.

Specify the filename like this:

```
 msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
```

Comment: So that half fixed it. Now they are showing up as PDF file and I am able to view them in the browser. But they still have 'noname'

Comment: You have to specify the name. If you look at the code you will see it doesn't put the filename anywhere in the message. It can't be picked up from `open()`, you know.

Comment: I didn't test your code I got it to work by adding `Name` keyword into the `msg = MIMEBase('application', "pdf", Name=file)`  like so

Answer (score 4):

Joe's comment fixed similar situation I had with a text file.  For your example, type:

```
msg = MIMEBase('application', "pdf", Name=file)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, just put the Name=file into the MIMEBase call

Comment: Fixed my issue too, thx!